# proper way to maintain and use ARCHIVE in CRAN like repositories

Tags: r, repository, package, cran

I wish to create a CRAN - like repository for my R packages. I am looking for instance at package `miniCran`. However I would also need to:

1. keep and organise as Archive all the previous versions (both source and binaries), so that I can
2. have a clean and easy way to revert back to a previous package version, stored in archive. Unarchive it basically (=move it out of archive, and update the PACKAGES index file)

Is there a proper way to do that?

Comment: @Pascal I don't think so, my question is on what is not covered by the other question, ie the versioning of packages, and the maintenance of the old packages

Comment: I don't think it is the way a CRAN mirror is supposed to work.

Comment: how should it work then, and do you have any reference? I have found all documentation very elusive on the treatment of archive packages. How do I revert back a package version on all computers of my organisation?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess a CRAN mirror is supposed to provide the last version of any package, for different (supported) version of R. However, you can try to work with `download.packages` and `tools::write_PACKAGES`, as well as `options(repos = c(CRAN = ...))`. But as archived packages are only the source (not compiled), it might be complicated for non-*nix R version.

Comment: indeed, my plan is to keep as well in my CRAN like repository the compiled version in archive

Comment: Seems I was wrong: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/  There is an access to old compiled version of packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100939/discussion-between-rockscience-and-pascal).

Comment: @Pascal the archive doesn't contain all versions of compiled packages, only one per R release.

Comment: @thomas So I was partially correct. Didn't have time to dig further.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [**drat** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drat/index.html) is for. The ["drat for Package Authors" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drat/vignettes/DratForPackageAuthors.html) has a good overview of what you do here. You can create a local drat repository or host one somewhere remotely, like GitHub (which is what drat defaults to). (It's not a mini CRAN but rather an R-compatible repository that allows you to install packages using `install.packages()`.)

Basically, to build a local drat repository you just do something like:

```
library("drat")
initRepo(name = "drat", basepath = "~/git")
insertPackage("myPkg_0.5.tar.gz", "~/git/drat")
```

This adds a local package tarball to the local drat repository. The default behavior is to leave all tarballs in one, top-level directory. `install.packages()` only sees the most recent (i.e., highest-versioned tarball for each package). There's an option, however, to create an Archive directory. The command looks basically the same:

```
insertPackage("myPkg_0.5.tar.gz", "~/git/drat", action = "archive")
```

This moves old versions to a CRAN-like Archive folder, leaving only the new release in the main directory.

This doesn't solve your problem of "reverting" the repository package to a previous version, basically because drat follows the CRAN philosophy that you never want to change the repository's history. With the Archive option, you can always install directly from the archive, however, without changing what's in the main drat folder.